# Set Range from another Range name

Tags: vba, excel

I am new with excel VBA. I am trying to make a function in my workbook which will do the excel linest function. I have a range (pqr) in which the first column is Y-variables and second column is X-Variable. I want to assign R1 and R2 as variables in the code. I tried to get code from other threads but this below is the code which I wrote...

```
Function LinestTest(pqr As Range)
 Dim vCoeff As Variant
 Dim r1 As Range
 Dim r2 As Range
 Set r1 = Range(pqr).Offset(, 1)
 Set r2 = Range(pqr).Offset(, 0)
 vCoeff = WorksheetFunction.LinEst(r1, Application.Power(r2, Array(1, 2, 3)))
 LinestTest = vCoeff
```

If I pass r1 and r2 separately, the code works.

Answer (score 1):

Since `pqr` is defined as `Range`, you need to apply the `Offset` property directly on it.

Replace:

```
Set r1 = Range(pqr).Offset(, 1)
Set r2 = Range(pqr).Offset(, 0)
```

with:

```
Set r1 = pqr.Offset(, 1)
Set r2 = pqr.Offset(, 0)
```

**B.T.W**

`Set r2 = pqr.Offset(, 0)` is equivalent to `Set r2 = pqr`

Answer (score 0):

This worked out..

```
    Function LinestTest(pqr As Range)
    Dim vCoeff As Variant
    Dim r1 As Range
    Dim r2 As Range
    'Set r1 = pqr.Offset(, 1)
    'Set r2 = pqr.Offset(, 2)
    Set r2 = pqr.Offset(0, 0).Resize(pqr.Rows.Count, pqr.Columns.Count - 1)
    Set r1 = pqr.Offset(0, 1).Resize(pqr.Rows.Count, pqr.Columns.Count - 1)

    vCoeff = WorksheetFunction.LinEst(r1, Application.Power(r2, Array(1, 2, 3)))
    LinestTest = vCoeff
End Function
```